# Why is my code unsuccessfully updating my mysql database (works sometimes)?

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I am very new to mysql and php. I am trying to write an iOS app for practice that basically lists books into a database by "listing". Here is a picture of my table for listings in the database:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0LLV.png]

The isbn is a global variable. I am positive that is not the problem. A lot of weird stuff happens and I can't figure out what the problem is. Sometimes the code will work how I intended it to, and the new listing will successfully get added to my table. Other times it does not add the row at all. When I NSLog **dataURL**, it displays (null) for the times that it works, and it displays <> for the times it works or partially works. I say partially works because sometimes for some reason it will not enter all of the deleteCode into the database table. It will enter everything fine except the deleteCode, in which case it enters a random number of the digits sometimes. It is always supposed to be 20 characters long yet sometimes it only enters in the first character, other time it enters in 10 characters, other times it enters in 18 characters... it is very weird. When I NSLog deleteCode it ALWAYS displays the correct 20 character deleteCode yet it isn't entering it into the database always... Please help me I am baffled :( The following is my iOS code:

```
#import "ListBookViewController.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

NSString *isbnSelling;

@interface ListBookViewController ()

@end

@implementation ListBookViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    codeToDeleteBook = [self generateDeleteCode];
    NSLog(@"%@", codeToDeleteBook);
    self.priceTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.emailTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.phoneTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.conditionTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    self.listBookButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    self.listBookButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.listBookButton.layer.borderWidth= 2.0f;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)isValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString
{
    BOOL stricterFilter = NO;
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}

- (IBAction)listBookButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // Making sure price is valid
    self.priceTextField.text = [self.priceTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
    self.priceTextField.text = [self.priceTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    if ([self.priceTextField.text rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        self.errorLabel.text = @"Price must be rounded by the dollar. EXAMPLE: 50";
        return;
    }

    NSScanner* scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self.priceTextField.text];
    int val;

    if([scan scanInt:&val] && [scan isAtEnd])
    {
        if([self.priceTextField.text intValue] > 999)
        {
            self.errorLabel.text = @"Maximum price to list a book at is $999.";
            return;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        self.errorLabel.text = @"Invalid price.";
        return;
    }



    // Making sure email address is valid
    self.emailTextField.text = [self.emailTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    if(![self isValidEmail:self.emailTextField.text])
    {
        self.errorLabel.text = @"Invalid email.";
        return;
    }

    if([self.emailTextField.text length] > 49)
    {
        self.errorLabel.text = @"Email must be smaller than 50 characters.";
        return;
    }



    // Making sure phone number is valid
    self.phoneTextField.text = [self.phoneTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    self.phoneTextField.text = [self.phoneTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];

    NSScanner *scan2 = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self.phoneTextField.text];
    int val2;

    if(!([scan2 scanInt:&val2] && [scan2 isAtEnd]))
    {
        if(![self.phoneTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![self.phoneTextField.text isEqualToString:@"N/A"])
        {
            self.errorLabel.text = @"Invalid phone number.";
            return;
        }
    }

    self.errorLabel.text = @"";

    if([self.phoneTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
        self.phoneTextField.text = @"N/A";



    if([self internetReachable])
    {
        [self.priceTextField setEnabled:false];
        [self.emailTextField setEnabled:false];
        [self.phoneTextField setEnabled:false];
        [self.conditionTextField setEnabled:false];
        [self.listBookButton setEnabled:false];


        if([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
        {
            if([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported])
            {
                UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

                __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;

                background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
                    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
                    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                }];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                    // Entering data into Listings table
                    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.org/addListing.php?deleteCode=%@&isbn13=%@&price=%@&email=%@&phone=%@&condition=%@", codeToDeleteBook ,isbnSelling ,self.priceTextField.text, self.emailTextField.text, self.phoneTextField.text, self.conditionTextField.text];
                    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
                    NSLog(@"%@", dataURL);

                    // Entering data into ContactInfo table
                    NSString *strURL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.org/addContactInfo.php?email=%@&phone=%@", self.emailTextField.text, self.phoneTextField.text];
                    NSData *dataURL2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL2]];


                    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
                    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;


                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        self.bookListedImage.hidden = false;
                        self.deleteCodeLabel.hidden = false;
                        self.deleteCodeLabel.text = codeToDeleteBook;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        self.errorLabel.text = @"Could not connect to internet.";
    }
}

- (IBAction)startedEditingPriceTextField:(id)sender
{
    self.listBookButton.hidden = true;
}

- (IBAction)startedEditingEmailTextField:(id)sender
{
    self.listBookButton.hidden = true;
}

- (IBAction)startedEditingPhoneTextField:(id)sender
{
    self.listBookButton.hidden = true;
}

- (IBAction)startedEditingConditionTextField:(id)sender
{
    self.listBookButton.hidden = true;
}

- (IBAction)doneEditingPriceTextField:(id)sender
{
    self.listBookButton.hidden = false;
}

- (IBAction)doneEditingEmailTextField:(id)sender
{
    self.listBookButton.hidden = false;
}

- (IBAction)doneEditingPhoneTextField:(id)sender
{
    self.listBookButton.hidden = false;
}

- (IBAction)doneEditingConditionTextField:(id)sender
{
    self.listBookButton.hidden = false;
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    self.listBookButton.hidden = false;
    [self.priceTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.phoneTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.conditionTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(NSString *)generateDeleteCode
{
    NSString *deleteCode = @"";

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 62; // generates random number between 0 and 61 (62 different random characters)

        switch(randomNumber)
        {
            case 0:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
                break;

            case 1:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"&"];
                break;

            case 2:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"2"];
                break;

            case 3:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"3"];
                break;

            case 4:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"4"];
                break;

            case 5:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"5"];
                break;

            case 6:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"6"];
                break;

            case 7:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"7"];
                break;

            case 8:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"8"];
                break;

            case 9:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"9"];
                break;

            case 10:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"q"];
                break;

            case 11:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"w"];
                break;

            case 12:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"e"];
                break;

            case 13:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"r"];
                break;

            case 14:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"t"];
                break;

            case 15:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"y"];
                break;

            case 16:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"u"];
                break;

            case 17:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"i"];
                break;

            case 18:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"o"];
                break;

            case 19:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"p"];
                break;

            case 20:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"a"];
                break;

            case 21:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"s"];
                break;

            case 22:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"d"];
                break;

            case 23:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"f"];
                break;

            case 24:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"g"];
                break;

            case 25:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"h"];
                break;

            case 26:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"j"];
                break;

            case 27:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"k"];
                break;

            case 28:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"*"];
                break;

            case 29:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"z"];
                break;

            case 30:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"x"];
                break;

            case 31:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"c"];
                break;

            case 32:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"v"];
                break;

            case 33:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"b"];
                break;

            case 34:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"n"];
                break;

            case 35:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"m"];
                break;

            case 36:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"Q"];
                break;

            case 37:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"W"];
                break;

            case 38:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"E"];
                break;

            case 39:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"R"];
                break;

            case 40:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"T"];
                break;

            case 41:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"Y"];
                break;

            case 42:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"U"];
                break;

            case 43:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"%"];
                break;

            case 44:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"$"];
                break;

            case 45:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"P"];
                break;

            case 46:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"A"];
                break;

            case 47:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"S"];
                break;

            case 48:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"D"];
                break;

            case 49:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"F"];
                break;

            case 50:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"G"];
                break;

            case 51:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"H"];
                break;

            case 52:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"J"];
                break;

            case 53:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"K"];
                break;

            case 54:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"L"];
                break;

            case 55:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"Z"];
                break;

            case 56:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"X"];
                break;

            case 57:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"C"];
                break;

            case 58:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"V"];
                break;

            case 59:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"B"];
                break;

            case 60:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"N"];
                break;

            case 61:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"M"];
                break;

            default:
                deleteCode = [deleteCode stringByAppendingString:@"?"];
                break;
        }
    }

    return deleteCode;
}

- (BOOL)internetReachable
{
    char *hostname;
    struct hostent *hostinfo;
    hostname = "example.org";
    hostinfo = gethostbyname(hostname);

    if (hostinfo == NULL)
        return false;

    else
        return YES;
}

@end
```

Below is my php and mysql code:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","editedOut","editedOut","editedOut");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$deleteCode = $_GET["deleteCode"];
$isbn13 = $_GET["isbn13"];
$price = $_GET["price"];
$email = $_GET["email"];
$phone = $_GET["phone"];
$condition = $_GET["condition"];

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Listings
VALUES ('$deleteCode', (NOW() + INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '$isbn13', $price, '$email', '$phone', '$condition')");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Ensure `$price = $_GET["price"];` is a float or integer maybe?

Comment: Hmm. I thought I was accomplishing that with this line of code :S if([scan scanInt:&val] && [scan isAtEnd]) else it returns before even activating the php web server script.